# Django by example, 1.2 or 1.5 is better to learn?

Tags: python, django, web

Should i do the 1.2 version of django or 1.5 on lightbird.net? because the updated version seems a little bit dependent on the libraries -CBV. Any suggestions? because I'm just a beginner and am confused with the libraries while 1.2 version seems straightforward though.

Comment: Do people still use 1.2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django 1.2 was released 3 years ago and is not maintained anymore. So as a beginner, you should definitely learn Django 1.5.

Comment: but the tutorials using mcbv libraries which im not familiar with. Any suggestion? or should i learn other stuffs? Thanks

Comment: Hmm are you following https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/ ? There is only 1 small part of part 4 which introduces generic views there. And in general you should learn CBVs sooner or later. Please note that you can still use function based views in Django 1.5.

Comment: I've done the tutorial and looking to deepen my knowledge in django, but couldn't find great resources except the site lightbird.net. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Go for this one then: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/. Then create your own project to harden your skill. Follow this for best practices http://lincolnloop.com/django-best-practices/